# eclipse source code editor plugin to use with ANTLR

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, eclipse-rcp, antlr

I've created my 'new programming language' using the ANTLR framework. The language is defined by its grammar and semantics are enforced using tree walkers that traverse the AST.

I want to develop an eclipse plugin to serve as a source code editor to write programs in my new language. 
For example I would like to highlight keywords, mark lines with syntactic/semantic errors, etc.

What is the best way to approach this? 
Anyone knows of any lib/framework which integrates easily with ANTLR to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) framework, it is based on ANTLR + EMF. Fully functional source code editor with customizable autocomplete + quickfix... can be done easily with that

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. after some research I understood that Xtext requires some modification to my ANTLR grammar. Such modification is not that simple. also It does not provide a "new perspective" and "new project" features. I saw the [IMP framework](http://www.eclipse.org/imp/). It seems it currently does not fully support ANTLR as the parser generator, but the users guide specifies it is possible. maybe anyone here has some experience how to use IMP to develop the IDE to be used with ANTLR?

Comment: Xtext does provide a customisable new project wizard, this is configurable in the workflow mwe2 file. The perspective extension point is simple enough to extend once the view(s) and editor(s) exist. Xtext will get you fast something that will last (a metamodel namely).

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse [dltk](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) plugin would be the better option for this.

Comment: I've never used xtext, but it looks promising to me. I know projects like [XQDT](http://www.xqdt.org/html/index) use DLTK for xquery editing.